# How would I express an interval between two imaginary numbers?

Tags: complex-numbers

For example, how would I say "between -i and i"?

Comment: You mean all numbers in the straight line joining $-i$ and $i$?

Comment: the line segment joining $-i$ and $i$.

Comment: Yes the line segment joining -i and i (the straight line).

Answer (score 1):

Let the set that contains all points between $-i$ and $i$ is $S$, then we can write$$S=\{i\cdot r|r\in(-1,1)\}$$

Answer (score 0):

The line segment ranging from a point $u$ to a point $v$ is the set of points:

$$\{u\cdot t + v\cdot (1-t)~:~t\in [0,1]\}$$

This is true for all vector spaces over the reals, including complex numbers.